# R Markdown kable table using $ sign in column name for html output

Tags: html, html-table, r-markdown, kable, dollar-sign

I'm wanting to include the units in my column description for a kable table in R Markdown with html output.
Basically for each cost I want 'Cost Min ($k)', 'Cost Mode ($k)' and 'Cost Max ($k)' as 3 of my column names.

It works fine for my first table but then for my second it is outputting it with strange formatting and not reading each column name correctly.

[image: html output]

My code is as follows:

```
Summary<- matrix(c(0.90,0.99,1000,3000,5000,0.90,0.99,1000,3000,5000,0.30,0.60,500,750,1000), ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)

colnames(Summary)<-c("Probability Lower","Probability Upper" , "Cost Min ($k)" , "Cost Mode ($k)" , "Cost Max ($k)")
rownames(Summary)<-c("Start", "Current", "Target")
SummaryTable<-as.table(Summary)

knitr::kable(SummaryTable, format = "html") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(SummaryTable,bootstrap_options = "bordered")
```

Any help would be much appreciate as I would like all my tables to look like the one that is working.

Laura

Answer (score 1):

Try using two backslashes before the dollar sign, like this: `\\$`:

```
colnames(Summary)<-as.character(c("Probability Lower","Probability Upper" , "Cost Min (\\$k)" , "Cost Mode (\\$k)" , "Cost Max (\\$k)"))
rownames(Summary)<-c("Start", "Current", "Target")
```

[image]